# Does MySQL block nested loop optimizer switch affect query results?

Tags: mysql, configuration, query-optimization

If I set `set optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off'` as suggested [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69721), can i get 100% certainty the same result for option `on` and `off` ?

I want to change this option to `off`, because it increases query performance in my case from 56s to 1s.

What are the pros and cons for this optimizer switch, is it safe?

Comment: If you can't post company code then make an example of your own code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I do not think this is necessary because it is not the key point of the question.

Comment: You could remove the part of the question that is not relevant. Just summarize the first 2 paragraphs into something like 'There are some queries that are very slow but if I set ...' etc.

Comment: I edited your title, I hope that's okay. It's better to phrase the title in the form of a question.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you, now it's perfect ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. The `optimizer_switch` tells MySql how to search for the answer to the query. Regardless of how `optimizer_switch` is set, it will generate the same result for your query (unless there are bugs in MySql).

The only disadvantage to using `set optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off'` is that other queries might become slower, so you might want to set it back to `on` after executing your query.

Comment: Thank you if nobody else answear i will accept this. However i dont know why my question get so many minuses...

Comment: @Daredzik I think it's because the first two paragraphs is about code we can't see, that isn't even relevant. If you change your question to something like 'Am I guaranteed to get the same result if I use this optimizer_switch?', it is a lot clearer what the question is.

Comment: i hope its fine now ;)